# json file not recognised in typescript

Tags: json, typescript, protractor

I am writing a protractor testfile which has to get data from json 
   file(`data.json`) like this

```
{
   "url":"https://example.com/login",
   "email":"nov@example.uk",
   "password":"uhi",
   "text_name":"random"
}
```

The protractor test file is

```
   'use strict';
   import { browser, element, by, protractor, $$, $ } from protractor
   import { Classtext } from "../pages/MainPage";
   var datatest = require('../utility/resource/data.json');
   describe('', function () {  
   var object1 = new Classtext();    
   it('load url', function () {       
   welcom.openBrowser("https://example.com");
   });
   });
```

when I compile, I get this error.

```
 [13:37:22] E/launcher - Error: Error: Cannot find module 
   '../utility/resource/data.json'
```

Here data.json path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the path from

```
var datatest = require('../utility/resource/data.json');
```

to

```
var datatest = require('../../utility/resource/data.json');
```

because in typescript all ".ts" files will be compiled to ".js" files and they will be stored in the directory which is provided in typescript config file.